Angular AuthGuard Not Blocking Access When Directly Navigating to blocked Routes
I'm working on an Angular application where I want to prevent authenticated users from accessing the login and signup pages. I have implemented an AuthGuard to handle this. The guard works as expected when navigating within the application using Angular's router, but it fails to block access when the user directly enters the login or signup URL in the browser's address bar.
when the application starts it attempts to get current user
app.component.ts - - >
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    RouterModule,
    LoaderComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  authService = inject(AuthService);
  destroy = inject(DestroyRef);
  title = 'book store';
  router = inject(Router);
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
      this.authService
        .getCurrentUser()
        .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroy))
        .subscribe();
    }
  }
}


auth.service.ts relevant part - - >

 currentUser: WritableSignal<CurrentUser | null | undefined> = signal(undefined);

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<CurrentUser> {
    return this.http.get<CurrentUser>(`${environment.API_URL}/auth/user`).pipe(
      tap((response) => {
        this.currentUser.set(response);
       
      })
    );
  }

app.routes.ts relevant part - - >
 {
    path: 'login',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/auth/login/login.component').then(
        (m) => m.LoginComponent
      ),
    data: { title: 'login' },
    canActivate: [authGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/auth/signup/signup.component').then(
        (m) => m.SignupComponent
      ),
    data: { title: 'signup' },
    canActivate: [authGuard],
  },

my problem is that the my guard uses currentUser signal from AuthService  and the value emitted by the signal is undefined when the guard is executed witch allows the user to access the blocked page.
auth.guard.ts - - >
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, type CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (_route, _state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  const user = authService.currentUser();
  // when I directly enter the login or signup URL I see AuthGuard: currentUser: undefined
  console.log('AuthGuard: currentUser:', user);

  if (user === null || user === undefined) {

   // I see this log when I directly enter the login or signup URL in the browser's address bar

    console.log('AuthGuard: No user found, allowing access.');
    return true;
  } else {

 // the guard works correctly when I navigate to /login or /signup from a router link or by going back

    console.log('AuthGuard: User found, redirecting to home.');
    router.navigateByUrl('/');
    return false;
  }
};


Any insights or suggestions to ensure the guard works correctly regardless of how the route is accessed would be greatly appreciated!

The guards are working correctly, the problem seems to be the logic behind it, a solution could be to try to use APP_INITIALIZER to run the logic of the logged user before any routing.
function initializeUser(authService: AuthService): Promise<any> {
   if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
      return firstValueFrom(authService.getCurrentUser())
    }
    return Promise.resolve()
}

app.module.ts
  providers: [{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initializeUser,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AuthService]
    }],

In this way the user (if any) will be loaded before the application routing and now you have access to the user in the guard.
Also give a look to https://v17.angular.io/api/router/CanMatchFn.

thank you for your answer, Since I'm using Angular 18, which doesn't have modules, I made some adjustments. Instead of adding the initializer function in app.module.ts, I included it in my app.config.ts file under the providers section.
Here's the modified code:
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (authService: AuthService) => async () => {
    await authService.initializeUser();
  },
  deps: [AuthService],
  multi: true,
} 

I had to wrap the initializer function with async and await to ensure that the initializeUser method completes before the guard executes.

When working with a guard, which fires just once one route navigation, I think it's safe to make the API call, since it's an infrequent occurrence and you will always have the latest value.
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, type CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (_route, _state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return authService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
    map((user: CurrentUser) => {
      if (user === null || user === undefined) {
        console.log('AuthGuard: No user found, allowing access.');
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('AuthGuard: User found, redirecting to home.');
        router.navigateByUrl('/');
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};


Yes, this might also work.
